# Construct an XPath using class and text of a div element

Tags: html, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am trying to construct a relative xpath to use with webdriver, but I am having trouble getting any of the ones I've tried to work.

My Web Element:

```
<div class="pa-PrimaryNavWidget-hyperlink" style="color: rgb(255, 255, 255); cursor: default; background-color: rgb(0, 173, 239);">Home</div>
```

I've figured out the absolute path of the element:

```
html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]
```

I have tried:

```
//div[contains(@class, 'pa-PrimaryNavWidget-hyperlink') and text()='Home']
//div[@class='pa-PrimaryNavWidget-hyperlink’ and text()='Home’]
//div[contains(.,'Home')]
```

Comment: Generally, your xpath looks fine. Maybe the element was just loaded dynamically. Have you tried to add some sort of "wait": http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
//div[@class="pa-PrimaryNavWidget-hyperlink" and text()='Home']
```